# How to let variable become immutable after one change?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, immutability

first value from event data:

```
A = 100;
start_value = A;
start_value = 100
```

but A is constantly changing due to `JSON.parse(evt.data)` from sensors

so after a while if:

```
A = 500
start_value = 500
```

How do i fix start_value = the first JSON data from websockets?

I've tried `Object.freeze()`, `Object.assign()`, however, the problem is since start_value is derived from A, it will always be changed. Is it possible to fix the start_value using the first value of A?

Comment: Stop assigning to `A` once it has reached a threshold…? `A` isn't changing on its own, it's changing because you're assigning to it, no?

Comment: the sensors run continuously, cannot stop assign to A..

Comment: How does `A` change exactly…? Is it a property of an object that updates itself? Are you assigning a value to it in a websocket event handler?

Comment: A is changed when sensors sent parseJSON data over..yes it updates itself.. no not assigning a value to it

Comment: you're talking about websocket and JSON. There's no data that the server can send that will change some variable in your app. There has to be some JS code on your end that takes the recieved data and updates `A` and `start_value`. can you include the relevant parts of that code.

Comment: function doSend()
  {
    var jsonGetData = {"command": 1, "sensors":["pressure","temperature"]};
    var jsonGetDataAll = {"command": 2};                                   

    if(msgReceived)
    {
      console.log("SENT: " + JSON.stringify(jsonGetData));
      websocket.send(JSON.stringify(jsonGetData));
      msgReceived = false;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

use `Closure` keep original value.

```js
const origin = (init) => () => init

let A = 100
const originA = origin(A)
let start_value = originA()
// 100

A = 500
start_value = originA()
// 100
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is the A = 100 gets changed to 500 at the top ..